# How to determine if a connect with a Winsock timeout has succeeded

Tags: c++, windows, networking, tcpclient

I used [the following C++ code](https://qiita.com/hidetaka0/items/501ad17b4c23c3adee03) to create a TCP/IP client. In actual use, I use it in a loop and keep checking for connections until the server is ready.

This code keeps looping through the order 0.2, 0.6, 1 before connecting to the server.

After a successful connection to the server, nothing is printed. No errors are printed, and almost nowhere is passed.

How do I know TCP/IP made a successful connection?

```
int connect_timeout(int & socket, struct sockaddr * name, int namelen, timeval timeout)
{
    unsigned long mode = 1;
    int result= ioctlsocket(socket, FIONBIO, &mode);
    if(NO_ERROR != result)
    {
        //std::cout << "0.0---------------" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        //std::cout << "0.1---------------" << std::endl;
    }

    result= connect(socket, name, namelen);
    if(SOCKET_ERROR == result)
    {
        int errono = WSAGetLastError();
        if(WSAEWOULDBLOCK == errono)
        {
            std::cout << "0.2---------------" << std::endl;
            errono = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //std::cout << "0.3---------------" << std::endl;
            mode = 0;
            ioctlsocket(socket, FIONBIO, &mode);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "0.4---------------" << std::endl;
    }

    mode = 0;
    result= ioctlsocket(socket, FIONBIO, &mode);
    if(0 < result)
    {
        //error
        std::cout << "0.5---------------" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "0.6---------------" << std::endl;
    }
    
    fd_set readFd, writeFd, errFd;
    FD_ZERO(&readFd);
    FD_ZERO(&writeFd);
    FD_ZERO(&errFd);
    FD_SET(socket, &readFd);
    FD_SET(socket, &writeFd);
    FD_SET(socket, &errFd);
    int sockNum = select(socket + 1, &readFd, &writeFd, &errFd, &timeout);
    if(0 == sockNum)
    {
        //timeout
        std::cout << "1---------------" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else if(FD_ISSET(socket, &readFd) || FD_ISSET(socket, &writeFd) )
    {
        std::cout << "2---------------" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //error
        std::cout << "3---------------" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "4---------------" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ winsock2, how to tell when a connection closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522555/c-winsock2-how-to-tell-when-a-connection-closes)

Comment: It might actually be easier to use a blocking socket in a sub-thread.  Non-blocking sockets can be a bit of a pain.

Comment: SupaMaggie70 b
That is a question about the server, my question is the client. And it doesn't say what I want to know because there is no code.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b that post doesn't even come close to answering this question. That post is about detecting a graceful closure after the socket is connected. This post is asking how to detect the socket is connected in the first place.

Comment: If the connection fails you need to close the socket. It is now useless. Putting it back into blocking-mode is pointless. Using `select()` on a blocking-mode socket is pretty pointless, and introduces various opportunities for error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`connect()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) says:

> With a nonblocking socket, the connection attempt cannot be completed immediately. In this case, connect will return `SOCKET_ERROR`, and `WSAGetLastError` will return `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. In this case, there are three possible scenarios:
>
> - **Use the `select` function to determine the completion of the connection request by checking to see if the socket is writable.**
> - ...
>
> Until the connection attempt completes on a nonblocking socket, all subsequent calls to `connect` on the same socket will fail with the error code `WSAEALREADY`, and `WSAEISCONN` when the connection completes successfully. Due to ambiguities in version 1.1 of the Windows Sockets specification, error codes returned from `connect` while a connection is already pending may vary among implementations. **As a result, it is not recommended that applications use multiple calls to `connect` to detect connection completion.** If they do, they must be prepared to handle `WSAEINVAL` and `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error values the same way that they handle `WSAEALREADY`, to assure robust operation.
>
> ...
>
> For connection-oriented, nonblocking sockets, it is often not possible to complete the connection immediately. In such a case, this function returns the error `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. However, the operation proceeds.
>
> When the success or failure outcome becomes known, it may be reported in one of two ways, depending on how the client registers for notification.
>
> - **If the client uses the `select` function, success is reported in the `writefds` set and failure is reported in the `exceptfds` set.**
> - ...

And the [`select()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) says:

> The parameter `writefds` identifies the sockets that are to be checked for writability. **If a socket is processing a `connect` call (nonblocking), a socket is writable if the connection establishment successfully completes.** ...
>
> The parameter `exceptfds` identifies the sockets that are to be checked for the presence of OOB data or any exceptional error conditions.
>
> Note  Out-of-band data will only be reported in this way if the option `SO_OOBINLINE` is FALSE. **If a socket is processing a `connect` call (nonblocking), failure of the connect attempt is indicated in `exceptfds` (application must then call `getsockopt` `SO_ERROR` to determine the error value to describe why the failure occurred).** This document does not define which other errors will be included.

You are turning off the socket's non-blocking mode *before* you are calling `select()`.  You need to wait for the non-blocking `connect()` operation to complete before you can then mess around with the socket's settings.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int connect_timeout(int & socket, struct sockaddr * name, int namelen, timeval timeout)
{
    u_long mode = 1;
    int errNo;

    int result = ioctlsocket(socket, FIONBIO, &mode);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == result)
    {
        errNo = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Unable to set socket to non-blocking mode. Error: " << errNo << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Connecting..." << std::endl;

    result = connect(socket, name, namelen);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == result)
    {
        errNo = WSAGetLastError();
        if (WSAEWOULDBLOCK == errNo)
        {
            fd_set writeFd, errFd;
            FD_ZERO(&writeFd);
            FD_ZERO(&errFd);
            FD_SET(socket, &writeFd);
            FD_SET(socket, &errFd);

            result = select(socket + 1, NULL, &writeFd, &errFd, &timeout);
            if (SOCKET_ERROR == result)
            {
                errNo = WSAGetLastError();
            }
            else if (0 == result)
            {
                result = SOCKET_ERROR;
                errNo = WSAETIMEDOUT;
            }
            else if (FD_ISSET(socket, &errFd))
            {
                result = SOCKET_ERROR;
                errNo = 0;
                int len = sizeof(errNo);
                getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&errNo, &len);
            }
            else
            {
                result = errNo = 0;
            }
        }

        if (SOCKET_ERROR == result)
        {
            if (WSAETIMEDOUT == errNo)
                std::cout << "Connection timed out" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Unable to connect. Error: " << errNo << std::endl;

            mode = 0;
            ioctlsocket(socket, FIONBIO, &mode);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl;

    mode = 0;
    result = ioctlsocket(socket, FIONBIO, &mode);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == result)
    {
        errNo = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Unable to set socket to blocking mode. Error: " << errNo << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```